# Error: cannot find symbol: variable Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to implement a native module which provides connection service in react native. But I am facing an error. As I am not an android/java developer, I am not being able to find the cause of the following error.

```
E:\projects\deets-mobile-cp\node_modules\react-native-connection-service\android\src\main\java\com\genm\CallConnection.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)
                                  ^
      symbol:   variable O_MR1
      location: class VERSION_CODES
    E:\projects\deets-mobile-cp\node_modules\react-native-connection-service\android\src\main\java\com\genm\CallConnection.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
            setConnectionProperties(PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED);
                                    ^
      symbol:   variable PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED
      location: class CallConnection
```

**CallConnection.java**

```
package com.genm;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.telecom.Connection;
import android.util.Log;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)
public class CallConnection extends Connection{

    public CallConnection(){
        setConnectionProperties(PROPERTY_SELF_MANAGED);
        setAudioModeIsVoip(true);
    }

    @Override
    public  void onAnswer(){
        Log.d(TAG, "On answer to the call");
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the sdk version of your project ?

Comment: it's value is `27`... while the Android SDK might not be properly installed.

Comment: It's using Android SDK Build Tools version `27.0.3`. compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: download latest build tools set them to your project and try.

Comment: Be sure that you have compileSdkVersion = 27 in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Thanks @MatPag changing the `compileSdkVersion` to `27` worked for me.

Comment: @Shivam I've added it as answer (if you want you can accept it), maybe could help other people :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Be sure that you have `compileSdkVersion = 27` in your `build.gradle` file

> `compileSdkVersion` is the SDK level which will be used to compile your
>   app. If you need to access properties or methods added on API 27 you
>   need to update this value accordingly. This means that if you needed to access (for example) `Build.VERSION_CODES.P` you should have set `compileSdkVersion = 28` and so on...